# Losing information by using overflow in CSS in a dash interface

Tags: css, user-interface, plotly-dash

I'm currently programming with dash in Python and so using CSS
My problem is the next one :

```
dbc.Row(
                                id="kpi-selector",
                                children=[
                                    html.H3(id="kpi-selection-title",children="Select all KPIs you want to calculate"),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    html.Div(
                                        id="kpi-selection-div",
                                        children=[
                                            add_kpi(nb_kpi_tests)]),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    html.Br(),
                                    html.Div(
                                        id="selection-buttons",
                                        children=[
                                            dbc.Button(
                                                id="reset-kpi",
                                                children="Reset selection",
                                                n_clicks=0,
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ],
                            ),
```

```
def add_kpi(number):
    final=html.Div(id="checklists-div", children=[])
    cmpt = 1
    part = html.Div(
        id=f"checklist{cmpt}",
        className="checklists",
        children=[],
        )
    
    for i in range (number):
        if (i%2)==0 and i!=0:
            final.children.append(part)
            cmpt += 1
            part = html.Div(
                id=f"checklist{cmpt}",
                className="checklists",
                children=[],
                )
            part.children.append(add_checkbox(i))
        else:
            part.children.append(add_checkbox(i))
            
    final.children.append(part)
    
    return final
        
    


def add_checkbox(number):
    return html.Div(
        className="each-kpi-div", 
        children=[
            daq.BooleanSwitch(id={'type': 'kpi-switch', 'index': number},className="kpi-checkbox"),
            html.H3(f"KPI_{number}"), 
            html.Button(id={'type': 'kpi-definition', 'index': number},className="help-kpi",children="?"),
        ],
    )
```

(My code isn't optimize yet)

And this is the CSS file :

```
#kpi-selector {
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 40rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #2d3038;
}

#kpi-selection-title {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;   
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a0abb0;
}

#kpi-selection-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem; /* Modifier la hauteur en conséquence */
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: safe-center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#checklists-div {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.checklists {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row; 
}

.each-kpi-div {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 2% 0 2%;
}
```

This is what my GUI currently looks like :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AMYE.png)

As you can see, I’m at the top of the scroll bar, but KPI selection starts at the seventh element.
Before adding the scroll bar, I had no problem with the selection, all items were displayed.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

i can't tell i tried a lot of things because i'm kinda new with css and python. I searched for solution on internet but nothing conclusive.

Edit : the nb_kpi_tests value is a variable value, currently at 25

The thmslmr answer was the right one, wasn't expecting something that simple, but thank you thmslmr !

Comment: Can you provide the `nb_kpi_tests` value please ?

Comment: Try removing the `justify-content: center` in the `#kpi-selection-div` rules.